# CreateFeatureClass failure in vb.net

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

I'm using ArcGIS 9.3.1 and trying to get the code to create a new feature class in an existing personal geodatabase to work but I am having no luck. When running in debug mode from within vb.net it will fail with the standard "LoaderLock" error where it tells you to not run managed code inside a DllMain.

````
Dim pGeomDefEdit As IGeometryDefEdit = CType(pGeomDef, IGeometryDefEdit)

With pGeomDefEdit

    .GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon

    Dim pSpatRefFact As ISpatialReferenceFactory2 = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.SpatialReferenceEnvironment

    Dim pGeoCoordSys As IGeographicCoordinateSystem = pSpatRefFact.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem(ESRI .ArcGIS.Geometry.esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS19 84)

    .SpatialReference_2 = pGeoCoordSys

End With


Dim pFields As IFields = New Fields

Dim pFieldsEdit As IFieldsEdit

Dim pField As IField

Dim pfieldEdit As IFieldEdit


pFieldsEdit = pFields

pField = New Field

pfieldEdit = pField


With pfieldEdit

    .Name_2 = "ObjectID"

    .Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeOID

End With

pFieldsEdit.AddField(pField)


pFieldsEdit = pFields

pField = New Field

pfieldEdit = pField

With pfieldEdit

    .Name_2 = "SHAPE"

    .Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry

    .GeometryDef_2 = pGeomDef

End With

pFieldsEdit.AddField(pField)


Dim pWorkSpaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory = New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.AccessWorkspaceFactory

Dim pFWS As IFeatureWorkspace = pWorkSpaceFactory.OpenFromFile("c:\Dan\Data\DataFi tness-1AOI.mdb", 0)


Dim pFeatClass As IFeatureClass

Dim pUID As New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID

pUID.Value = "esriGeoDatabase.Feature"


'FAILING HERE

pFeatClass = pFWS.CreateFeatureClass("TestFC1", pFieldsEdit, pUID, Nothing, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "SHAPE", "") ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that's the cause of the problem, but singleton classes (`SpatialReferenceEnvironment` and `AccessWorkspaceFactory`) should not be created directly, but through [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) calls.

Anyway, I have also encountered LoaderLocks in the past, but have never been able to get to the root of the problem. I believe it has to do with the order libraries are loaded in, and it usually occured when working with WinForms at some point.

I usually disabled the LoaderLock MDA (debugging assistant) in VS debugger settings. This does not seem to cause any other problems, at least I didn't experience any.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as been solved.  I was not defining the XY domain of the spatial reference for the geometry field.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in place of your last (failing) line:

```
pFeatClass = pFWS.CreateFeatureClass("TestFC1", pFields, Nothing, Nothing, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "SHAPE", String.Empty)
```